# Visual Studio Code Debug Console colors?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to display colors (like in a terminal) in the Debug Console of Visual Studio Code (Version 1.10.2) when debugging node.js code?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To output coloured messages from nodejs in visual studio you can use formatted message in console.log method. for example :

```
console.log('\u001b[' + 32 + 'm' + 'hello stack' + '\u001b[0m')
```

as implemented in [Mocha](https://github.com/mochajs/). 32 is a color code. Other color codes and usage sample you can find in theirs repo: https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/9e95d36e4b715380cef573014dec852bded3f8e1/lib/reporters/base.js#L48

[image]

Or as a log library you can use, for example [pinojs](https://github.com/pinojs/pino) + [pino-pretty](https://github.com/pinojs/pino-pretty) module and your log output will be displayed as here :

[image]

Comment: Works for java, too: System.out.println("\u001b[32mhello stack\u001b[0m"); =>colors in terminal.

Answer (score 24):

See @ https://stackoverflow.com/a/55493884/3645650 for lore and roleplay.

Here is just a no brain answer.

|  | Versions |
| --- | --- |
| Tested up to | Visual Studio Code May 2021 (version `1.63`) |

#### Text

```
console.log( "\u001b[1;31m Red message" );
console.log( "\u001b[1;32m Green message" );
console.log( "\u001b[1;33m Yellow message" );
console.log( "\u001b[1;34m Blue message" );
console.log( "\u001b[1;35m Purple message" );
console.log( "\u001b[1;36m Cyan message" );
```

#### Background

```
console.log( "\u001b[1;41m Red background" );
console.log( "\u001b[1;42m Green background" );
console.log( "\u001b[1;43m Yellow background" );
console.log( "\u001b[1;44m Blue background" );
console.log( "\u001b[1;45m Purple background" );
console.log( "\u001b[1;46m Cyan background" );
```

#### Reset

```
console.log( "\u001b[0m Reset text and background color/style to default" );
```

#### Example

```
console.log( "\u001b[1;31m --process: Error" + "\u001b[0m" );
```

Answer (score 15):

I guess so far the best way is to put your debug output into alternate destinations:

In Launch Configuration Attributes the `console` setting can be set to one of the following: `internalConsole` (default, the builtin Debug Console) `externalTerminal` (external cmd window) or `integratedTerminal` (the VS Code terminal).

The external terminal command line can further be specified in the VS Code Settings under one of the following: `terminal.external.windowsExec`, `terminal.external.osxExec`, and `terminal.external.linuxExec` from the default that is your default os terminal.

Source: VS Code docs, for example for node.js: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_launch-configuration-attributes

Comment: the `externalTerminal` also displays it without colors when using the Jest extension debug function..

Answer (score 8):

For best results, also avoid opening the console.  Here's my config for debugging the current file with Jest:

```js
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Jest Test (current)",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "args": [
        "--config=jest.config.json",
        "--runInBand",
        "${relativeFile}",
    ],
    // The vscode console does not support colors used by Jest output
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
}
```

Answer (score 8):

v1.45 is adding a bunch of debug theme colors, see https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#new-debug-theme-colors

`debugView.exceptionLabelForeground`: Foreground color for a label shown in the CALL STACK view when the debugger breaks on an exception

- `debugView.exceptionLabelBackground`: Background color for a label shown in the CALL STACK view when the debugger breaks on an exception
- `debugView.stateLabelForeground`: Foreground color for a label in the CALL STACK view showing the current session's or thread's state
- `debugView.stateLabelBackground`: Background color for a label in the CALL STACK view showing the current session's or thread's state
- `debugView.valueChangedHighlight`: Color used to highlight value changes in the debug views (ie. in the Variables view)
- `debugTokenExpression.name`: Foreground color for the token names shown in debug views (ie. the Variables or Watch view)
- `debugTokenExpression.value`: Foreground color for the token values shown in debug views
- `debugTokenExpression.string`: Foreground color for strings in debug views
- `debugTokenExpression.boolean`: Foreground color for booleans in debug views
- `debugTokenExpression.number`: Foreground color for numbers in debug views
- `debugTokenExpression.error`: Foreground color for expression errors in debug views

---

And in v1.46 ([v1.46 release notes](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_46.md#new-debug-console-theme-colors)), some debug console themeable items are being added:

- `debugConsole.infoForeground`: Foreground color for info messages in debug console
- `debugConsole.warningForeground`: Foreground color for warning messages in debug console
- `debugConsole.errorForeground`: Foreground color for error messages in debug console
- `debugConsole.sourceForeground`: Foreground color for source filenames in debug console
- `debugConsoleInputIcon.foreground`: Foreground color for debug console input marker icon

---

Specific to inline values displayed during debugging (not in the debug console but the variable values shown at the end of lines within the code), a couple of new colors are being added to v1.57:

> New colors were added to theme the inline values:
>
> - `editor.inlineValuesBackground`: color for the debug inline value foreground text
> - `editor.inlineValuesForeground`: color for the debug inline value background.
>
> As a reminder inline values are shown during debugging for debug
> extensions that have inline value providers registered or if the
> setting `debug.inlineValues` is `true`.

Comment: Is there nothing for background colours? I can't see what I'm highlighting. Any way to change the highlight colour?

Answer (score 5):

Click on Settings Icon on bottom left of Visual Studio

[image: Settings Visual Studio]

Click on Settings

[image]

Search for `workbench` and under that,  click on the sub-heading `appearance`.
Then click on `Edit in settings json`

[image: Search workbench]

Scroll down, and add the following code in the end:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    
        "debugConsole.infoForeground": "#00ff66"
    }
```

Change the color code as per your choice.

[image]

Boom! Every "info" logs are in green color now!

If you want to change for error, warn, etc logs, just add the following under  `"workbench.colorCustomizations": { ... }`

Refer this answer for what to add : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525127/9420335

Comment: This changes only the main color of the console, but it is asked in the question to pick the colors of each log message.

Answer (score 2):

My Setup, coloured steps:

I think the main attribute to the colour here is `--format=node_modules/cucumber-pretty`

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible Node.js debug attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "console": "integratedTerminal",
        "name": "Cucumber",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/tests/cucumberjs/node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/tests/cucumberjs",
        "args": [
            "--tags=@luke",
            "--format=node_modules/cucumber-pretty"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: And apparently when using `"console": "integratedTerminal"` this is redundant (has no effect) `"outputCapture": "std"`

Comment: Yes, this seems to be true, therefore I have removed it from the config example

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `--colors` argument worked for me. (I'm using jest).

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [{
    "type": "node",
    "name": "vscode-jest-tests",
    "request": "launch",
    "args": ["--colors"],
    "runtimeArgs": [
      "--inspect-brk",
      "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
      "--runInBand"
    ],
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen",
    "port": 9229
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using "colors" package from npm. It is very easy to use and you can use features like bold and underline as well. Here is the url for it's documentation:-  https://www.npmjs.com/package/colors

Answer (score 1):

Really quick and dirty for Java console from a Java noob:

```
private static void debugLog(String msg) {
  if (msg.indexOf("Exception") > -1) {
    System.out.println("\u001b[31m" + msg + "\u001b[0m");
  } else {
    System.out.println("\u001b[32m" + msg + "\u001b[0m");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
console.log("\u001b[1;32m" + 'This is your message!!!' + "\u001b[0m"); //Green message with escape
    
console.log("\u001b[1;31m" + 'This is your message!!!' + "\u001b[0m"); //Red message with escape
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little utility I wrote based on the answers here (and some googling):

```js
export const colored_console = {
  /**
   * @param color red | green | yellow | blue | purple | cyan | red_bg | green_bg | blue_bg | purple_bg | cyan_bg | yellow_bg | white_bg
   * @param args things you want to log
   */
  log: function(color, ...args) {
    // adjust text color
    if      (color === 'red'      ) { console.log(`\u001b[31m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    else if (color === 'green'    ) { console.log(`\u001b[32m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    else if (color === 'yellow'   ) { console.log(`\u001b[33m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    else if (color === 'blue'     ) { console.log(`\u001b[34m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    else if (color === 'purple'   ) { console.log(`\u001b[35m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    else if (color === 'cyan'     ) { console.log(`\u001b[36m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    // adjust bg color
    else if (color === 'red_bg'   ) { console.log(`\u001b[41m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    else if (color === 'blue_bg'  ) { console.log(`\u001b[44m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    else if (color === 'purple_bg') { console.log(`\u001b[45m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    else if (color === 'cyan_bg'  ) { console.log(`\u001b[46m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    // adjust text and bg color for better visibility
    else if (color === 'green_bg' ) { console.log(`\u001b[42m\u001b[34m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    else if (color === 'yellow_bg') { console.log(`\u001b[43m\u001b[34m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    else if (color === 'white_bg' ) { console.log(`\u001b[47m\u001b[34m`, ...args, `\u001b[0m`) }
    // if you didn't specify a color, log everything with default color
    else                            { console.log(color, ...args) }
  }
}
```

...and here's some further reading I found useful:

[Google Search: ANSI colors](https://www.google.com/search?q=ANSI%20colors) (check out the image results)

[Wikipedia: ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to customize the colors for `console.debug()` statements because I am typically using `console.info()` (and higher) statements in production code, whereas unit tests use `console.debug()` for additional analytic information.

Unfortunately, Javascript considers `console.info()` and `console.debug()` essentially the same. Only some browsers will suppress `console.debug()`. Visual Studio Code also does not provide a separate option to configure a different color for debug-level output.

However, a few other responses on SO to this and other posts let me to this simple solution to print `console.debug()` statements in a different color.

```
const PURPLE = "\u001b[35m";
const consoleDebugOrig = console.debug;
console.debug = function (...args) {
    consoleDebugOrig(PURPLE, ...args, PURPLE);
};
```

You could even use this approach to apply other types of formatting to debug outputs, like indentation or prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make reusable fnc like below to print in diff colors of foreground and background :
Works in debug console and terminal of VS Code :

```
function Prnt(MsgPsgVar, FgdClrPsgVar=0, BgdClrPsgVar=0)
{
    let PfxCodVar = "\u001b[1;"
    let ClrCodVar = "\u001b[0m"
    let ClrCodCfgVar={
        "red":"1",
        "green":"2",
        "yellow":"3",
        "blue":"4",
        "purple":"5",
        "cyan":"6"
    }
    let FgdStrCodVar=""
    let BgdStrCodVar="" 
    if (FgdClrPsgVar && ClrCodCfgVar[FgdClrPsgVar])
    {
        FgdStrCodVar = PfxCodVar + "3" + ClrCodCfgVar[FgdClrPsgVar]+"m"
    }
    if (BgdClrPsgVar && ClrCodCfgVar[BgdClrPsgVar])
    {
        BgdStrCodVar = PfxCodVar + "4" + ClrCodCfgVar[BgdClrPsgVar] + "m"
    }
    console.log(FgdStrCodVar, BgdStrCodVar, MsgPsgVar, ClrCodVar)
}
```

Using :

```
Prnt("Txt to Print","green")
Prnt("Txt to Print", 0,"green")
```