# How to search the debug console in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

This is [currently a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4338), so I know the answer isn't straight forward, but I assume some clever people found clever workarounds for this.

One way is to copy/paste the output in some text editor, but ew.

Someone suggested redirecting the debug output to the terminal, which does have a search feature, sounds better.

So, the question is, how does one redirect the debug output to the terminal?

Unless, of course, you have an even better solution.

**EDIT** (from the GitHub thread)

> You can use the property "console": "integratedTerminal" on the debug
>   launch task to redirect the output to the terminal.

Comment: someone has already replied to your question on gihub ;)

Comment: @Jaya héhé, thanks!
I'll still leave the question open in case something better comes along though.

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44186259/3066295) is how to set the property mentioned in your edit.

Comment: Go to root folder of project and type "flutter logs"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since August 2020 and VSCode 1.49, [the Debug Console does support filtering](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_49.md#debug-console-filter):

> ### Debug Console filter

> The Debug Console now supports filtering, making it easier for users to find the output they are looking for, or to hide irrelevant logging output.
>
> The filter also supports exclude patterns (for example, patterns starting with an exclamation mark `!`).
> The filter only applies to program output, but not to evaluations run by a user.
>
> Like other input boxes in VS Code, you can use the up and down arrow keys to navigate between old filter inputs.
>
> In the short video below, the output is filtered to entries that include the text '`http`', do not include the text '`http`' (using the filter `!http`), and then include the word '`Severity`':
>
> [image: Debug Console filtering -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_49/filter.gif]

<sup>(Click on the picture to enlarge. Look for the filter at the top right section of the animation)</sup>

---

And with the upcoming [Sept. 2020 VSCode 1.50](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_50.md#debug-console-filter-improvements), you know where you are in your search:

> Since last milestone the Debug Console supports filtering, making it easier for users to find the output they are looking for, or to hide irrelevant logging output.
>
> Now we have added a badge to make it clear how many items are filtered away.
>
> [image: Debug console badge -- https://media.githubusercontent.com/media/microsoft/vscode-docs/vnext/release-notes/images/1_50/debug-console-badge.png]

---

Nov. 2023, [Sattar Hummatli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3702595/sattar-hummatli) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268169/how-to-search-the-debug-console-in-vscode/64076436?noredirect=1#comment136466036_64076436):

> Go to root folder of project and type "`flutter logs`"

---

As noted by [Troopers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2753802/troopers) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268169/how-to-search-the-debug-console-in-vscode/64076436#comment137086102_64076436):

> You can combine filters (`AND`) using a comma:
>
> ```
> !native, !result
> ```

Comment: Filtering is cool and all, but what if what I need is a search? I want to find lines and see their context.

Comment: @GregorA.Lamche True, this is not the same as a search.

Comment: I just want to read through the output without having to use the very fiddly mouse scrollbar. Arrow keys don't work. I have to copy and paste to Notepad++. Every. Time.

Comment: @Resource I agree, that is frustrating.

Comment: Go to root folder of project and type "flutter logs"

Comment: @SattarHummatli Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @VonC is there a way to combine filters like `!native && !result`

Comment: @Troopers Not sure (I cannot test it at the moment). Try ` !native !result `

Comment: @VonC a comma between filters is needed `!native, !result`

Comment: @Troopers Good catch, well done! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. Thank you for this feedback.

Answer (score 30):

Looks like this answer is now outdated, see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64076436/2745495) instead.

---

A type-to-filter functionality has been added. To use it:

1. Give focus to the debug console (By clicking it, for instance.)
2. Press `cmd + F` / `ctrl + F`
3. Start typing

You will see what you type in the upper right corner of the debug console.

[image: The little text box that appears top right corner of the debug console]

You can then "enable filter on type" (the 3 lines left of the 'x') and only matching lines will show in the debug console. Press Escape to clear the search.

So it's not exactly the search feature OP was looking for, plus you can't type spaces, but it's the best built in tool for now (July 2019).

Comment: This is an unfortunate state of affairs :/

Comment: I'd disagree @AntonyStubbs, sure it's not obvious, but it does keep the UI simple but allows the functionality to exist?

Comment: It’s unfortunate not just because it’s hard to find, but also because of its limitations - see above.

Comment: No, it's bad all over because it's not even a proper search. It doesn't allow you to search for "list of something", as it doesn't allow spaces in the search, so it's essentially useless for searching custom logs in a human readable format.

Comment: @Antony Stubbs - unfortunate , especially since this was a solved problem in editors 30 years ago.

Comment: I only seem to be getting this filter to work in the Terminal tab but not in the Debug Console.

Comment: What I'm doing is copying all the lines to the clipboard and then opening a new window in the main text editor, pasting them in, and using the legit text search tools.

Comment: the correct answer is: the app does not provide a search feature. that is the only one, that can be accepted. unbelievable, btw.

Answer (score 0):

I recently stumbled upon the same issue and managed to find a workaround that did the trick for me. I thought I'd share it here in case it could help you or anyone else who's grappling with the same problem.

1. Navigate to the Keyboard Shortcuts section in VSCode `Code > Settings > Keyboard Shortcuts`.
2. Use the search bar to look for `cmd+f`.
3. After locating the command, check the `When` column, in my case it indicated that `Find` should always trigger if editor is open, even if not in focus `editorFocus || editorIsOpen`.
4. To make the command functional even when the terminal is in focus, modify the `When` value to `editorFocus || editorIsOpen && !terminalFocus` so that it checks if terminal is not in focus when cmd+F pressed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To have search instead of filter you need to go to root folder of project and type `flutter logs`