# How do I hide this message in the Flutter console - ViewPostIme pointer 0

Tags: android, flutter

Everytime I tap the screen of my device, I see this message in the Flutter console

`D/ViewRootImpl@38eee14[MainActivity]( 7994): ViewPostIme pointer 0`

followed by

`D/ViewRootImpl@38eee14[MainActivity]( 7994): ViewPostIme pointer 1`

These messages crowd the console and get in the way of reading actual important logs, so is there a way to get rid of them?

Comment: A better solution for this problem is addressed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437643/flutter-disable-system-debug-messages-in-run-tab

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did it with

```
flutter run | grep -v "D/ViewRootImpl"
```

Comment: not working flutter 3.7.7 (and dart 2.19.4)

Comment: @swifthing facing same issue, have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 8):

In VS Code, you can apply this search filter in the Debug Console:

```
!ViewPostIme
```

You can add more filters seperated by a comma:

```
!ViewPostIme,!ViewRootImpl
```

The '!' before a phrase excludes logs where the phrase occurs.

Example:

[image]

Comment: this approach is great

Answer (score 4):

Late to the party, but for me the previous answers didn't work.

In Android Studio's Console, there is an option "Fold lines like this" to fold (hide) lines based on a pattern. Just right-click on any line in the Console...

[image]

That worked for me! That way I was also able to Debug my app from Android Studio by using `Run 'main.dart'` (I prefer that) instead of Command Line.

In your case, you could just add "`D/`" (or "`D/ViewRootImpl`") there.
Also it is possible to use:

- `V/` (Verbose)
- `D/` (Debug)
- `I/` (Information)
- `W/` (Warning)
- `E/` (Error)
- `A/` (Assert)

Still to see only Flutter logs, also add "`I/flutter`" and "`E/flutter`" to the exceptions.

See the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b2miXG6HRNY

Answer (score 2):

You can always use:

```
flutter logs
```

instead.

Alternatively, if your using IntelliJ/ Android Studio, see:
[Flutter disable system debug messages in Run Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437643/flutter-disable-system-debug-messages-in-run-tab)