# How to remove unwanted informations from my console in android studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I need to remove those lines from my console!
When there is a change in my screen or a touch these things automaticaly
pops in my console which is much disturbing for me to concentrate on actual console detailes.

```
[        ] D/InputMethodManager( 2418): startInputInner - Id : 0
[        ] I/InputMethodManager( 2418): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
[        ] D/InputTransport( 2418): Input channel constructed: 'ClientS', fd=112
[   +4 ms] I/ViewRootImpl@aec25f4[MainActivity]( 2418): [DP] pd() Asnyc report
[   +8 ms] I/ViewRootImpl@aec25f4[MainActivity]( 2418): [DP] pdf(0) 1 android.view.ViewRootImpl.lambda$performDraw$1$ViewRootImpl:4668 android.view.-$$Lambda$ViewRootImpl$DJd0VUYJgsebcnSohO6h8zc_ONI.run:6 android.os.Handler.handleCallback:938 
[        ] I/ViewRootImpl@aec25f4[MainActivity]( 2418): [DP] rdf()
[        ] I/SurfaceControl( 2418): nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376651860042080]
[        ] I/SurfaceControl( 2418): nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376651860042080]
[        ] I/SurfaceControl( 2418): nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376651859971856]
[        ] I/SurfaceControl( 2418): nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376651859971856]
[ +289 ms] I/SurfaceControl( 2418): nativeRelease nativeObject s[-5476376651859991792]
[        ] I/SurfaceControl( 2418): nativeRelease nativeObject e[-5476376651859991792]
[+1419 ms] I/ViewRootImpl@aec25f4[MainActivity]( 2418): ViewPostIme pointer 0
[  +95 ms] I/ViewRootImpl@aec25f4[MainActivity]( 2418): ViewPostIme pointer 1
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/57064653/11039164