# How to filter Android Studio Flutter Console?

Tags: android, flutter

How to make android studio flutter console to show only flutter output? It is getting really unreadable when 
[Android studio flutter console showing logs of other processes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XShIP.png)

it started this behavior after I've executed this (Google Analytics event logs):

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

Comment: why dont you use `flutter logs`?

Comment: @pskink Didn't know about that, it works like a charm :)

Comment: @CopsOnRoad and the most normal way is to use `flutter run ...` where you can also have extra key bindings - press `h` for more info - i very often use `p` for example

Comment: @pskink yeah it might be solution, but I just do not want to android studio to show whole logcat of system.

Comment: I posted instructions for how to filter debug console messages for Flutter in Android Studio here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61622975/2301224

Answer (score 0):

this is answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62607771/12198530. hope it can help 
flutter v1.17.* makes this problem, so to remove this additional info and warning logs :
**1)** Install git 
**2)** do this commands by cmd in flutter folder

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
```

**3)** Delete flutter folder 
**4)** Download flutter v1.12.13+hotfix.5-stable and put it in the place of old flutter folder ( that you deleted in the previus step ).

It Worked Perfectly to me and it gives me only logs for my running flutter app ( I/flutter & W/flutter).
If it worked for anyone please let me know if this a right answer.