# logcat info appear in run tab in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, flutter, kotlin

my android studio run tab was simple like that:

[image: Simple View]

then it become harder and giving me more info like the info in logcat :

[image: Harder View]

How can I disable or remove the more info that appear in second picture and return to the first look in the first picture ?

I need only logs output for the running flutter apps. The command **flutter logs** do the job but I don't know why flutter console give me another logs with the logs of running flutter apps , all I need in flutter console is ( I/flutter and W/flutter ), I want to stop seeing the additional info and warning logs that have started appearing in console

Comment: Instead of checking the console on the run tab go to the logcat tab and check its filters. There is one on the right that says 'Show only selected application'

Comment: In **file -> settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Flutter -> General section , deselect Enable verbose logging** if it is currently selected.

Comment: i already unchecked it , i noticed there is more line appear on start run: (  Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55565/K6cAOtC2Yo4=/ws )

Comment: What information, exactly, do you want to see?

Comment: I/flutter , w/flutter ( only info coming from flutter )

Comment: @RyanM he wants to stop seeing the additional info and warning logs that have started appearing in console. Mark Sameh the Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55565/K6cAOtC2Yo4=/ws is for dart devtools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

flutter v1.17.* makes this problem, so to remove this additional info and warning logs :
**1)** Install git 
**2)** do this commands by cmd in flutter folder

```
git clean -xfd
git stash save --keep-index
git stash drop
git pull
```

**3)** Delete flutter folder 
**4)** Download flutter v1.12.13+hotfix.5-stable and put it in the place of old flutter folder ( that you deleted in the previus step ).

It Worked Perfectly to me and it gives me only logs for my running flutter app ( I/flutter & W/flutter).
If it worked for anyone please let me know if this a right answer.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

just press this icon after stop running the app

Comment: nothing happen , I think it is something with flutter console

Comment: this output is from console it self , I need to get log output  only for running Flutter apps.
the command ( flutter logs ) do the job but I don't know why flutter console show me another logs with logs from my flutter app.