# How to search ('Ctrl+F') in 'output' panel in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I used to be able to be able to `Ctrl+F` to search whatever was logged in `VS Code`. Now, for some unknown reason, the search bar doesn't show up when I type in `Ctrl+F`.

I am on version `1.57`, which is the latest at this time.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268169/how-to-search-the-debug-console-in-vscode) if for the **Debug Console** which isn't the tab I am looking at.

Answer (score 3):

Click anywhere inside the output panel, and then press Ctrl + F

Comment: This makes the cursor scroll down

Comment: hmm, if you go to file -> preferences -> keyboard shortcuts and search for "Find" do you see it bound as Ctrl+F and under the "When" column does it say: "editorFocus || editorIsOpen" ? if "when" doesn't say that you can right click and "change when expression" to edit it.

Comment: you should add your comment as part of the answer. i had an extension binding `ctrl+f`. after removing the keybinding of the extensions the search comeback to work again

Answer (score 1):

I realized that the Vim extension is what is causing this. `Ctrl+F` is for scrolling and although previously Vim keyboard shortcuts didn't work in the output panel, they seem to have been extended to it recently see [this issue](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/6780) I raised.