# How to search in VSCode test output

Tags: visual-studio-code

I run go tests using Testing panel in VSCode and some tests have a lot of logs. I want to search through them for a specific string, how can I do that? Ctrl+F doesn't work in "Test Output" panel (it just scrolls to the end).

I've tried to press Ctrl+F expecting that search panel will open, but it just scrolls the output to the end. I've checked keybindings to Ctrl+F and there are only "system" keybindings, i.e. no plugins involved. I've seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68076010/how-to-search-ctrlf-in-output-panel-in-vs-code#comment120337031_68082433) but it doesn't help too.

Comment: I tried Costa's answer and it works for me in all the **OUTPUT** panels, I have no test output panel but that should not be different to the git or ExtensionHost output

Comment: @rioV8 It works for me if I run the test using a small "run test" annotation above the test function in the editor - the test logs are in an "Output" panel. But if I run the test from a Testing panel (Flask icon on the left) then the test's output goes to a Terminal panel where Ctrl+F doesn't work.

Comment: in my terminal with prompt `Ctrl+F` works, what version of VSC do you use?

Comment: @rioV8 My question is about "Test results" panel, not terminal. I'm using Version: 1.81.1