# Cannot colorize output sent to debug console of VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

I am implementing a custom debugger using the [debug adapter protocol](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification) for VS Code (version 1.26.1). The debug adapter is written in Java and uses [LSP4J 0.5.0M1](https://github.com/eclipse/lsp4j) to communicate with the client.

Basic launching and evaluating expression already works. I am able to enter an expression in VS Code's *Debug Console* and have the debug server evaluate it.

Now I wanted to colorize the result returned from an `evaluate` request. For example, error messages for an expression that cannot be evaluated should be printed in red.

The request is sent as this:

```json
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 3,
  "method": "evaluate",
  "params": {
    "expression": "bad expression",
    "context": "repl"
  }
}
```

The response looks like this and contains ANSI escape codes to colorize the output:

```json
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 3,
  "result": {
    "result": "\u001b[31mFailed to evaluate expresion\n...\u001b[0m",
    "variablesReference": 0
  }
}
```

However, the escape codes are ignored and the output in the *Debug Console* is like this:

```
[31mFailed to evaluate expression:
...[0m
```

Various issues have been opened asking VS Code to support ANSI escape codes or reporting color support as broken, some of them listed below

- [Support colors in debug console](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/537)
- [Debug REPL lost coloring for escape sequences](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4616)
- [can not output string with color in debug console after update to 1.22.1](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/47457)
- [Add ability to display high intensity ANSI colors in debug console](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21423)

But all of them seem to be resolved.

Could anyone help me in finding the right response to have colored output in the *Debug Console*?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525127/836330 for some debug console colors being added to v1.46.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, ANSI color codes are not interpreted when the result of an evaluation request is shown in the debug console.

If ANSI escape codes should be considered, they need to be sent through the [`output` event](https://microsoft.github.io/debug-adapter-protocol/specification#Events_Output).