# How colors the debug console vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-debugger

It possible to have color in console debug.
at left it what i have on nwjs, and at right it what i have in vscode.
which plugin or parameter to add in vscode to get a result similar result to the one on the left.
thanks

Edit: see texts and objs log colors. **Firefox,chrome** have color syntax, but am not understand why vscode doesn't have it ? It essential for dev productivity.
[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528123/visual-studio-code-debug-console-colors/61525127#61525127 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_45.md#new-debug-theme-colors for new theme colors for various debug items.

Comment: And for debug console colors, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61525127/836330.