# How to change console.log() output in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, colors, console.log

I want to change color for some of my console.log() statements. Make some of them red and others green. Is there a way to do it if I use VSCode console to run my code?

Comment: See this discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528123/visual-studio-code-debug-console-colors

Comment: You can use chalk: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, You can do that in VScode, using a package called [chalk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chalk):-

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
 
console.log(chalk.red('Hello world!')); //will turn your log into red.
```

**Can also customize the theme according to your preferences, even it supports various styles, modifiers, background colors**

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
 
const error = chalk.bold.red;
const warning = chalk.keyword('orange');
 
console.log(error('Error!'));
console.log(warning('Warning!'));
```

Comment: Thanks, good idea. Although I wanted to do it without additional packages. But anyway it seems like the only solution

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the accepted answer you can use chalk, but you can also do it without any additional package, just by using ANSI colors, for example the following:

```js
 console.log('\x1b[31m red text \x1b[0m');
```

outputs a red text in the console (the `\x1b[31m` instructs the console to color the text red and the `\x1b[0m` instructs it to reset the colors to the default, so that subsequent `console.log`s aren't red colored too).

For various color codes you can for example check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/abritinthebay/d80eb99b2726c83feb0d97eab95206c4#file-consolecolors-js).

Also I wrote this very simple vscode extension which provides snippets that do that for you (so that you don't need to remember the color codes): [Console Colored Logs Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dariopiotrowicz.console-colored-logs).

Answer (score -3):

No, the console messages are displayed in browser.
You can however try using alternatives like:

1. `console.warn()`
2. `console.error()`

Refer to [this](https://medium.com/@shra1dhar/things-you-dont-know-about-the-console-api-javascript-97772b008310) for more details.

Comment: No, console.log in node.js displays messages on the sever, not the browser

Comment: The OP is running it from her VSCode. The rest should be obvious. @slebetman

Comment: Knick, as slebetman said, this message is displayed on the server, not on browser...