# How to display ANSI colors in VSCode debug console?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger, ansi-escape, ansi-colors

I debug the xv6 kernel in VSCode, but the debug console doesn't seem to support ANSI colors perfectly.I don't know how to make it display ANSI colors correctly.
[What my Debug Console shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gzxos.png)

I have tried to find a solution to the problem, and I have noticed that this problem was mentioned in an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/21423) of VSCode, and the issue has been solved by PR. I feel that my problem is similar to what is described in this issue, but I have not been able to solve it.

I also tried this in PR, and when I debugged the ts program, the Debug Console seemed to work fine. However, when I debug a C/C++ program (xv6 kernel), ANSI colors are not displayed correctly.
[What my Debug Console shows when I tried to debug TypeScript file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaLze.png)

Comment: check this one... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43528123/visual-studio-code-debug-console-colors

Comment: Hmm, why does the output have an `e` where the ESC character should be? I'm not familiar with all the systems you're using, but is it possible they're trying to use a `\e` in a string to get the ESC character, but the underlying system doesn't support it?

Comment: I think this might have something to do with the language I'm debugging, because I've tried debugging node.js code and it does show ANSI colors. But when I Debug C/C++ code, the Debug Console doesn't display ANSI colors correctly. (You can see the debug console output in the image for my problem.)

In addition, my system is Ubuntu22.04 for WSL2 under Windows11.

Comment: Looks like I found the cause of the problem. I used the [GDB Dashboard](https://github.com/cyrus-and/gdb-dashboard) and its output is colored, but VSCode's Debug Console doesn't display its output colors correctly. So when I disable GDB Dashboard with `dashboard -enabled off` in GDB, there is no ANSI color problem.

But in fact, I don't know why the output of GDB Dashboard is not displayed correctly in the Debug Console. I guess this is a problem with VSCode or a bug in GDB Dashboard